# Можно ли прервать все подпроцессы вызванные через php exec?

Tags: php, linux, bash

Я запускаю sh скрипт который запускает в свою очередь другие скрипты и вызывает выполнение например внутри декора процессов. В общем целая череда процессов. Если я это делаю из консоли и потом нажимаю Ctrl+c то все прерывается, все отлично. Мне нужно добиться тоже эффекта при выполнении через php -r "exec('script.sh')".
Я пытался прервать и php процесс и тот процесс который запускает php но это приводит лишь к остановке того процесса который я убил, а вышестоящие и нижестоящие продолжают выполнение.

Можно ли как-то скопом остановить всю ветку процессов, как это делатся в терминале при нажатии Ctrl+c?

В чем разница?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP функция getmypid() возвращает номер процесса, он же является и номером группы порождаемых процессов. Чтобы отправить сигнал группе процессов (а не процессу), надо поставить знак "-" перед ID. Если номер процесса 35, то убить этот и порожденные процессы можно так: `kill -9 -35`